# Digital Rights Management solution for PDF/Word sent by e-mail

Tags: security, pdf, ms-word, adobe, drm

I'm seeking a way where I can protect documents (Word/PDF) from being forwarded to another unauthorized users via email.

Our analysts write their opinion on a specific topic and then e-mail them to our clients (paid subscribers). Problem is that our clients can click FW to the entire universe and we lose money.

One way to circumvent this is by sending a link to a secured-site where they will be asked to use login w/pw but I wonder if there's an existing tool of some kind that does "digital Rights Management" so the file will not open unless you're subscribed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A foolproof way does not exist, and cannot exist.

If a user can see it, nothing will stop him from capturing the content and sending it on. The next to impossible to defeat: a video camera capturing it ...

But you can make it harder:

**Mark files**

Mark the files to indicate who they are intended for, along with copyright notices etc. Makes it easier to both know who forwarded it, and makes it much scarier to forward it for the user as their details (e.g. email address etc. are in it). It also allows you to see recurring problem customers and take action against the individuals.

**Password protect the file**

Formats like PDF, word etc. have some (easily defeated) ways to protect the files from unauthorised opening. But it also greatly affects the legitimate users as they'll have to enter the password as well. Add to that that including the password in the email defeats the "forwarded email" problem.

**Closed clients**

Using an app on a system like the iPhone might be a different approach: you don't email it and only make the content available to a client on a platform that is rather hardened by the maker (most users will not jailbreak their iOS device and as such you get a bit more control over the apps on them). Have the client app send notifications, retrieve it from a server and display it.

**Website/passwords**

In you example of a login and password on a website: nothing is going to stop them there either to either share their password or capture the document/information and send that on ... You will still need far more.

**Balance**

In the end you must find a balance between what your legitimate users want and need (speedy access, no hurdles), with your needs for protecting it.
And that is a risk assessment you need to make: costs of protecting vs. costs of not protecting.

Personally: Considering what you seem to be doing, I'd go for marking PDF files and password protect them to prevent easy modification (but allow printing and viewing). I'd mark them with something like "For the personal use of first.last@example.com" or "For the internal use of Corporation, inc." or so on. Include that in low contrast in the margin of every page and then let your legal team draft letters to those who infringe on your rights...

Actually: add a unique serial number in the PDF and make it invisible in the output. Track it internally and you should even find out who's trying to remove their tracks.

Comment: Thanks swa66 for the deep analysis!